# Permutations of a Word on a Page

Tags: permutation, combinatorics

Forgive me for the lack of official phrasing; this is a problem given orally in class, as opposed to being written in a problem set. Using the English alphabet with no spaces, commas, periods, etc (and thus only working with twenty-six letters possible), how many possible orderings are there of a string of fifty characters that contain the combination "Johndoe" at some location in the set?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [Wikipedia has the formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation).

Answer (score 0):

Edit: was a little quick to answer, and overlooked something very obvious. Please see the new answer below

This is more suited for something like math or stats stackexchange. Having said, that, there are 26^(50-7)*(50-7) combinations. To see why, ask yourself: how many 50 letter permutations of the 26 letters exist? Now, we will reduce this set by adding the restriction that a 7-letter contiguous word must exist within any candidate permutation. This has the effect of "fixing" 7 letters and making them unable to vary. However, we can place this 7 letter string anywhere, and there are 43 positions to place it ("johndoe" at position 0, "johndoe" at position 1, all the way to position 43, since "johndoe" will not fit at position 44).